# Resize iframe and window on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I'm making a cricket registration website with a group of people who decided to use Ruby on Rails for the database management. We're also trying to make it one page, so I have the registration forms currently loading in on iFrames. I know this isn't ideal, and if we were using PHP, I'd be able to use Ajax, but I don't know any other way around using iFrames. The difficulty with this is, I can't resize these iFrames when a button inside them is clicked. For example, there is this:

```
<div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Player', f, :players %>
</div>
```

Which is a button inside the 'links' class that says "Add player". When clicked, it will extend the content downwards, populating it with more forms to fill in. However, because the Iframe already has it's height, it doesn't adjust properly, leaving the extra content hidden.

Is there any way I can fix this? Alternatively, is there any way I can avoid using iFrames while still maintaining the one page aspect?

Cheers guys!

Comment: Ruby on Rails doesn't let you use ajax? Anyway, iframes can have transparent backgrounds...

Answer (score 0):

there's a iframe onload event which can you override the existing height of you're iframe. Let say:

```
<iframe id='stipsImage' onload='iFrameLoaded()' src='http://...' />...</iframe>
```

then on your javascript:

```
//apply css on iframe when ready
iFrameLoaded() {
    $('#stipsImage').contents().find("body")
          .append($("<style> " +
                    " body{ text-align: center; } " +
                    " img{ width: 700px; height: 748px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc } " +
                         "</style> "));
    }
```